# how to sort list of dict by dict[key][key] in one line(Python3)

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort by uid

```
rsp=[
       {'user': {'uid': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}},
       {'user': {'uid': 5, 'name': 'Sid'}},
       {'user': {'uid': 2, 'name': 'Cas'}},
    ]
```

to

```
rsp=[
       {'user': {'uid': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}},
       {'user': {'uid': 2, 'name': 'Cas'}},
       {'user': {'uid': 5, 'name': 'Sid'}},
    ]
```

Ive tried this way.....but it doesn't work

```
result = sorted(rsp, key=itemgetter('user').itemgetter('uid'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a lambda function to the `key` argument:

```
result = sorted(rsp, key=lambda x: x.get('user', {}).get('uid', -1) )
```

In this case I am using `get` to ensure the sort does not fail if one of the elements does not have a `user` key, and any sub-dictionaries that do not have a `uid` key will be place first.

Comment: It will still fail if the `uid` key is absent, you would need to proivde a default interger value for that

Comment: I just added that :)

Comment: Ah good! also be aware they may wish to raise an error here rather than silently sort, it's not clear

Answer (score 4):

You can try this as your key to sort your list of dictionaries:

```
rsp.sort(key = lambda x: x['user']['uid'])

>>> rsp
[{'user': {'uid': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}}, {'user': {'uid': 2, 'name': 'Cas'}}, {'user': {'uid': 5, 'name': 'Sid'}}]
```